# Show description instead of excerpt, limit words and add read more

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to replace the excerpt of a product with the long description. Right now i'm using the following code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',       
'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'the_content', 10 );
```

The above code does the job, however, it displays the full description. I would like to somehow limit the words (length) that is displayed and add a "read more" button at the end.

Comment: Long description doesn’t support read more for products. There is no use for this since we show content on a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new function to process the value of get_the_content() to get only a max number of words and add a "Read more" link at the end:

```
function custom_single_product_summary(){
  $maxWords = 50; // Change this to your preferences
  $description = strip_tags(get_the_content()); // Remove HTML to get the plain text
  $words = explode(' ', $description);
  $trimmedWords = array_slice($words, 0, $maxWords);
  $trimmedText = join(' ', $trimmedWords);

  if(strlen($trimmedText) < strlen($description)){
    $trimmedText .= ' &mdash; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
  }

  echo $trimmedText;
}
```

Then use it in the original override code you were trying to use:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',       
'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 10 );
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
Changed the action hook to echo the value rather than return it, as WooCommerce expects the action to print the output.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, still doesn't show anything in the "excerpt" part of the product.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The action needed to echo the output rather than returning it from the function, in order for it to work.

Comment: should this code be placed in functions file of theme folder ?